# AS3 How to call a button from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a button that when you click on it, the ship fires a laser, but the button isn't working. I mean I didn't get any error when debugging, however it won't allow me to click on the button, but instead it allows me to click on my ship to fire. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

My Fire.as

```
package control {

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.Event;

import objects.Ship;

public class Fire extends MovieClip {
    private var my_x: Number;
    private var my_y: Number;

    private var ourShip: Ship;

    var mouseDown: Boolean;

    public function Fire(margin_left: Number, margin_bottom: Number,     ourShip_mc: Ship) {
        my_x = margin_left;
        my_y = margin_bottom;
        ourShip = ourShip_mc;

        if (stage) {
            init();
        } else {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
    }

    private function init(e: Event = null): void {
        if (hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE)) {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        this.x = my_x + this.width / 2;
        this.y = stage.stageHeight - my_y - this.height / 2;

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    private function onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        //EVENT DISPATCHER
        dispatchEvent(new Event("eventshoot", true));
        trace("Fire clicked");
    }

}
}
```

My Ship.as

```
package objects {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.JointStyle;

import control.Controller;
import control.Joystick;
import control.Fire;

public class Ship extends MovieClip {
    var mouseDown: Boolean;

    private var stageRef: Stage;
    private var key: Controller;

    private var speed: Number = 2.5;
    private var vx: Number = 0;
    private var vy: Number = 0;
    private var friction: Number = 0.93;
    private var maxspeed: Number = 8;

    //fire related variables
    private var fireTimer: Timer; //causes delay between fires
    private var canFire: Boolean = true; //can you fire a laser

    public var move_left: Boolean = false;
    public var move_up: Boolean = false;
    public var move_right: Boolean = false;
    public var move_down: Boolean = false;

    public function Ship(stageRef: Stage): void {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        key = new Controller(stageRef);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ShipMove);
        stage.addEventListener("eventshoot", firenow);

        //setup your fireTimer and attach a listener to it.
        fireTimer = new Timer(250, 1);
        fireTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fireTimerHandler, false, 0, true);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function ShipMove(event: Event): void {
        if (move_left)
            vx -= speed;
        else if (move_right)
            vx += speed;
        else
            vx *= friction;

        if (move_up)
            vy -= speed;
        else if (move_down)
            vy += speed;
        else
            vy *= friction;
    }

    public function firenow(event: Event) {
        fireLaser();
    }

    public function loop(e: Event): void {

        //update position   
        x += vx;
        y += vy;

        //speed adjustment
        if (vx > maxspeed)
            vx = maxspeed;
        else if (vx < -maxspeed)
            vx = -maxspeed;

        if (vy > maxspeed)
            vy = maxspeed;
        else if (vy < -maxspeed)
            vy = -maxspeed;

        //ship appearance
        rotation = vx;
        scaleX = (maxspeed - Math.abs(vx)) / (maxspeed * 4) + 0.75;

        //stay inside screen
        if (x > stageRef.stageWidth - 30) {
            x = stageRef.stageWidth - 30;
            vx = -vx;
        } else if (x < 30) {
            x = 30;
            vx = -vx;
        }

        if (y > stageRef.stageHeight) {
            y = stageRef.stageHeight;
            vy = -vy;
        } else if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
            vy = -vy;
        }

    }

    private function fireLaser(): void {
        //if canFire is true, fire a laser
        //set canFire to false and start our timer
        //else do nothing.
        if (canFire) {
            stageRef.addChild(new LaserGreen(stageRef, x + vx, y - 10));
            canFire = false;
            fireTimer.start();
        }
    }

    //HANDLERS      
    private function fireTimerHandler(e: TimerEvent): void {
        //Timer ran, fire again.
        canFire = true;
    }

    public function takeHit(): void {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("hit"));
    }
}

}
```

Updated, here's the Engine.as, sorry for not replying it to your comment below, the structure is messed up if I do so.

```
package objects {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;

import control.Joystick;
import control.Fire;

public class Engine extends MovieClip {
    private var preloader: ThePreloader;

    public function Engine() {

        preloader = new ThePreloader(474, this.loaderInfo);
        stage.addChild(preloader);
        preloader.addEventListener("loadComplete", loadAssets);
        preloader.addEventListener("preloaderFinished", showSponsors);
        stage.addEventListener("gameSTART", fGameStart);
    }

    private function loadAssets(e: Event): void {
        this.play();
    }

    private function showSponsors(e: Event): void {
        stage.removeChild(preloader);
        var ps: PrerollSponsors = new PrerollSponsors(stage);
        ps.addEventListener("prerollComplete", showMenu);
        ps.preroll();
    }

    private function showMenu(e: Event): void {
        new MainMenu(stage).load();
    }

    public static var enemyList: Array = new Array();
    private var ourShip: Ship;
    private var joystick: Joystick;
    private var fire: Fire;
    private var scoreHUD: ScoreHUD;

    public function fGameStart(evt: Event): void {

        ourShip = new Ship(stage);
        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);

        joystick = new Joystick(120, 70, ourShip);
        addChild(joystick);

        fire = new Fire(420, 70, ourShip);
        addChild(fire);

        scoreHUD = new ScoreHUD(stage);
        stage.addChild(scoreHUD);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function loop(e: Event): void {

        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) == 5) {
            var enemy: E1 = new E1(stage, ourShip);
            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemy.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy);
            stage.addChild(enemy);
        } else if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) == 5) {
            var enemy2: E2 = new E2(stage, ourShip);
            enemy2.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemy2.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy2);
            stage.addChild(enemy2);
        }

    }

    private function enemyKilled(e: Event) {
        scoreHUD.updateKills(1);
        scoreHUD.updateScore(e.currentTarget.points);
    }

    private function removeEnemy(e: Event) {
        enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    }

    private function shipHit(e: Event) {
        scoreHUD.updateHits(1);
    }

}

}
```

So every time the fire button (Fire.as) is clicked, it dispatched an event "eventshoot", and the ship (Ship.as) pick it up. And when the ship receive it, the ship itself fires a laser, that's the idea. But since there are prerolls, menus...stuff like that will loaded before starting the game, I can't just simply drag the fire button to the stage. The engine will load the ship, fire button, enemy, score... to the stage when game started. And I got a error 1009 when debugging "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.", it is from:

stage.addEventListener("eventshoot", fire now);

in Ship.as

I understand that I'm getting this error because there is no fire button on stage, so my ship can't pickup the "eventshoot" event, is there a way I can make the ship only pickup that event after making sure the button is loaded to the stage to avoid the error?

Comment: The line `private var stageRef:Stage;` is unnecessary. There's no point in having an additional reference to a `Stage` object. There are a lot of online tutorials out there that do this, please don't blindly copy from them. Make yourself familiar with the display list and how it works.

Comment: never post code in comments. **All related information should always be in the question**, don't scatter it around. You posted an `Engine` class, but it looks like it doesn't correspond to the `Ship` and `Fire` class that you've posted earlier. Please post all the code you have the way you have it right now and explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: Thats all the code I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you certainly can create a class for your button, the functionality to make the ship object fire a laser should not be in the button.

Given a `Ship` class that looks like this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    public class Ship extends MovieClip
    {
        public function fireLaser():void
        {   
            trace("pew pew");
        }
    }
}
```

You can instantiate this class and add it to your main timeline with this code:

```
var ship:Ship = new Ship();
addChild(ship);
```

If you placed the symbol by hand you do not need to do this and instead only need to give it an instance name of `ship`.

To make something clickable, add an event listener to it. For example, to make the ship itself clickable:

```
var ship:Ship = new Ship();
addChild(ship);

ship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("ship clicked");
}
```

If you have a button on the main time line with an instance name of `fire`, you can as easily add the listener to that button:

```
var ship:Ship = new Ship();
addChild(ship);

// v---this changed
fire.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("fire button clicked");
}
```

Last but not least, if you want to call a method on an object instead of using `trace()`, you can do that, too:

```
var ship:Ship = new Ship();
addChild(ship);

fire.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ship.fireLaser();  // this changed, laser fired "pew pew"
}
```

### tl, dr;

The button itself shouldn't do anything. If the button did anything with the ship directly, it would have to know the ship. **The button shouldn't know the ship.** All the button does is say "I got clicked" by dispatching an event, everything else should be handled outside.

You know, just like when you wrote your question here, it's not the entire internet (including me) sitting in the keyboard buttons of your computer listening to your input. All your keyboard buttons did was saying "I got clicked". Everything else got handled outside, by your operating system, browser, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) However, the button and ship will only be added to the stage when the game is started, which is handled by game_engine.as in my case. As you also mentioned, the button is like "I got clicked" by dispatching an event, I've changed my code in fire.as, so every time I click on it, it dispatch an event, and it will be pick up by ship.as, but then I get error 1009 (null object). I mean, I understand I am getting this because the button hasn't load to the stage yet, but is there a way check it, so my ship only pickup that event when the button is loaded to avoid this error?

Comment: @HinC.  You talk about a game_engine.as, as if I knew anything about it. Please include all relevant information in your question. Then I can help you. =)

Comment: I've just included the engine.as up there, sorry for not posting it here, the structure is messed up if I do so.

Comment: @HinC. While my answer assumes a `fire` button to be present and created by hand, it will work just the same when you create the `fire` button dynamically. As you can see, I create the `ship` dynamically.

Comment: @null uprooted for             trace("pew pew");